# How to prevent ListTile subtitle property expanding?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show some information under ListTile's title property but when I show informations the ListTile expanding spontaneously. I wrapped ListTile with Flexible doesn't work.How to prevent this?

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08yZA.gif)

Here is my code:

```
return Flexible(
  child: ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      leading: Container(
        width: 48,
        height: 48,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: prefixIconBackgroundColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        ),
        child: Icon(icon, color: primaryColor),
      ),
      title: priorityWidget == null
          ? Text(text,
              style: isInitial == true
                  ? secondaryHeadline.copyWith(color: Colors.grey[600])
                  : isColorRed == true
                      ? secondaryHeadline.copyWith(color: Colors.red)
                      : secondaryHeadline)
          : priorityWidget,
      subtitle: subtitle != null
          ? Text(subtitle, style: bodyText.copyWith(fontSize: 14))
          : null,
      trailing: trailing),
);
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the error: https://dartpad.dev/704f30b998aab08a4e46f23e4ebb16a3
Maybe try wrapping the List Tile inside a Container or something like it

Answer (score 0):

Try to this way

body: ListView(

children: [

ListTile(title: Flexible

```
        (

          flex: 1,

          child: Text("ListTil"),

        ),
          subtitle: Text("Sample Subtitle. \nSubtitle line 3"),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.home),
          isThreeLine: true,
        )],
      ),
```